# Using arrays when setting values in defaultConfiguration() of BlockForm in BlockBase

Tags: 8, blocks, plugins

I'm writing a block plugin that allows you to specify certain values for the block in the panel pane editor. 
I'm able to defined the default values using

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'plugins_string' => $this->t('Enter text here'),
        );
}
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $form['plugins_string_text'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => $this->t('Block contents'),
      '#format' => 'full_html',
      '#description' => $this->t('This text will appear in the block.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['plugins_string'],
    );


    $form['layout'] = array(
        '#type' => 'details',
        '#title' => t('Layout'),
        '#open' => FALSE,
        '#group' => 'layout', 
        );
    $form['layout']['pane-type'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Pane Type'),
        '#options' => array(
            'standard' => t('Standard Panel Pane'),
            'box' => t('Box Layout'),
            'column' => t('Column Layout'),
        ),
        '#description' => 'Choose what type of pane this is',
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['layout']['pane-type-submit'],
    );
}
```

I see how to generate the default configuration['plugins_string'] but I'm not sure how to load a default when it is in an array. Like configuration['layout']['panetype-submit']

I have already tried

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'plugins_string' => $this->t('Enter text here'),
        array('layout', 'pane-type-submit') => 1,
        );
}
```

and

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'plugins_string' => $this->t('Enter text here'),
        'layout', 'pane-type-submit' => 1,
        );
}
```

Both of these were not successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'plugins_string' => $this->t('Enter text here'),
        'layout' => array('pane-type-submit' => 1),
     );
 }
```

Comment: That still doesn't work for me for some reason

Comment: The keys of your options are 'standard', 'box' and 'column'. So you should replace the 1 above by the key you want as default value.